# Adding DimpleJS charts to div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dimple.js

I have two charts which I have created using DimpleJS. I want to place them side by side on my webpage. Using bootstrap grid, I am facing some issues. Here is the basic outline of the grid structure which I am using:

```
<html>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="chart1">
  code of DimpleJS chart1 which binds it to div "chart1"
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="chart2">
  code of DimpleJS chart2 which binds it to div "chart2"
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

But when i do this, both my charts overlap each other on the right side of the webpage. Don't know what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way but, for myself I did this to display two chart horizontally.

```
   <div>
       <div id="chart1" style = "float:left;width:45%;"</div>
       <div id="chart2" style = "float:right;width:45%;"</div>
  </div>
```

make sure you put this between your  tag

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us the code for creating the Dimple plots, but were you trying to set fixed height and width on the svg?  If you have a fixed size svg and it exceeds the pixel width of the bootstrap column, then the charts may overlap or be cut off.  To avoid this, set both the height and width on the svg in your Dimple code to be "100%".  Also, Dimple won't resize these charts by itself, so you should add a window.onresize handler to do it.

Finally, are your charts maintaining an aspect ratio? Ring and pie charts will maintain an aspect ratio, while bar charts will not.  (Not sure about line charts or others.)  If so, then you might also want to set a fixed height on the container div to prevent the plot from becoming poorly sized when the container div is not square:  it prevents excessive downward travel when the div is very tall and thin, and it prevents ridiculously huge plots when the div is very wide.

Study the following stripped down example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
  <script src="/lib/d3.v4.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          <div id="test1" style="height: 400px;"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco    laboris...</p>
          <div id="test2" style="height: 400px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    var data = [{x:"Gopher", o:100},
                {x:"Julie", o:100},
                {x:"Steubing", o:100},
                {x:"Isaac", o:100},
                {x:"Doc", o:100}];

    var makeChart = function(ele, data) {
        svg = dimple.newSvg(ele, "100%", "100%");
        chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        chart.setMargins(40,40,40,40);
        chart.addMeasureAxis("p", "o");
        var ring = chart.addSeries("x", dimple.plot.pie);
        ring.innerRadius = "50%";
        chart.addLegend(40,20,50,120,"right");
        chart.draw();    
        return chart;
    };

    var chart1 = makeChart("#test1", data);
    var chart2 = makeChart("#test2", data);

    window.onresize = function() {
        chart1.draw(0,true);
        chart2.draw(0,true);
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```